# Fast way to get closest point from each quadrant

Tags: python, algorithm, nearest-neighbor, closest

I want to quickly (say, <1 ms) perform a nearest neighbor search by quadrant.

Input of each search:

- a fixed set of points in 2D space (black points in image). This remains constant across searches, so it can be stored in an efficient data structure. Number of points between 1 and 1000.
- a point whose location is different for each search (red point in image). Abstractly, this divides the 2D space into 4 quadrants (separated by red lines in image) much like the origin in a Cartesian coordinates.

Output of each search:

- black point from *each* red quadrant that is closest (circled blue in image) to the red point.

[image: Two searches of nearest neighbors per quadrant]

The output should usually be 4 points, one from each quadrant. But there are some possible edge cases:

- a quadrant to have no black points; collect no points for this quadrant
- a quadrant has multiple ties; collect all such points for this quadrant
- same point lies on boundaries (red lines) of quadrants: do not collect that point more than once

Things that I know won't work:

- nearest point along just one axis, say x, can be very far away (circled green in image)
- second closest point in a quadrant (circled purple in image) may be closer than points in the other quadrants. A simple search for the red point's 4 nearest neighbors will collect this point I don't want.

EDIT: version of accepted answer's code, and timings

```
def trial1(quadneighbori,
           printout = False, seedN = None, Npts = 1000, Niter = 1000):

    if seedN != None: np.random.seed(seedN) # random seed

    # Generate Npts (x,y) coordinates where x and y are standard normal
    dataset = np.random.randn(Npts,2)

    for n in range(Niter):
        # Generate random pixel (x,y) coordinates where x and y are standard normal
        red = np.random.randn(1,2)
        dst, i = quadneighbori(dataset, red)
        if printout: print(dst, i)

def quadneighbor1(dataset, red):
    dst = np.zeros(4)
    closest = np.zeros((4,2))

    # Work out a Boolean mask for the 4 quadrants
    right_exclu = dataset[:,0] > red[0,0]
    top_exclu =   dataset[:,1] > red[0,1]
    Q1 = np.logical_and( top_exclu, right_exclu)
    Q2 = np.logical_and(~top_exclu, right_exclu)
    Q3 = np.logical_and(~top_exclu,~right_exclu)
    Q4 = np.logical_and( top_exclu,~right_exclu)
    Qs = [Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4]

    for Qi in range(4):
        # Boolean mask to select points in this quadrant
        thisQuad = dataset[Qs[Qi]]
        if len(thisQuad)==0: continue # if no points, move on to next quadrant
        # Calculate distance of each point in dataset to red point
        distances = cdist(thisQuad, red, 'sqeuclidean')
        # Choose nearest
        idx = np.argmin(distances)
        dst[Qi] = distances[idx]
        closest[Qi] = thisQuad[idx]

    return dst, closest

# numba turns 1.53s trial1 to 4.12ms trial1
@nb.jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def quadneighbor2(dataset, red):
   redX, redY = red[0,0], red[0,1]
   # Distance to and index of nearest point in each quadrant
   dst = np.zeros(4) + 1.0e308           # Start large! Update with something smaller later
   idx = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.uint32)
   for i in nb.prange(dataset.shape[0]):
      # Get this point's x,y
      x, y = dataset[i,0], dataset[i,1]
      # Get quadrant of this point (minus 1)
      if x>redX:
         if y>redY:
             Qi = 0
         else:
             Qi = 1
      else:
         if y>redY:
             Qi = 3
         else:
             Qi = 2

      # Get distance (squared) of this point - square root is slow and unnecessary
      d = (x-redX)*(x-redX) + (y-redY)*(y-redY)
      # Update if nearest
      if d<dst[Qi]:
         dst[Qi] = d
         idx[Qi] = i

   return dst, idx
```

```
%timeit trial1(quadneighbor1)
111 ms ± 3.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit trial1(quadneighbor2)
4.12 ms ± 79.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

PS: `cdist` is `numba`-incompatible, but tweaking the line to remove `cdist` and adding `@nb.jit` to `quadneighbor1` speeds up `trial1(quadneighbor1)` from 111ms to 30.1ms.

Comment: Are you able to group your points according to which quadrants they belong ?

Comment: @auburg - I guess I can do that by brute force, just assigning each and every data point to the 4 quadrants defined by the arbitrary point (or, I could just keep the closest data point per quadrant). But the 4 quadrants change depending on the arbitrary point, so this would have to be calculated over and over. Therefore, I'm seeking less wasteful alternatives to brute force.

Comment: Is the quadrant origin (red point) also fixed or can each query have a different red point?

Comment: @Berthur The red point is variable, the black points are fixed

Comment: How many (black) points are there in total, please? And what sort of speed are you looking for?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Number and locations of data points (black points) are unknown but constant.

Comment: So somewhere between 7 and 7,000,000,000 is representative? Or wider than that?

Comment: I hadn't anticipated the size of the dataset mattering, but for my purposes, yes it will be well within that, <1000.
As for speed, I want to accomplish this search hundreds of times per second.

Comment: Is it possible to perform a pre processing step where (as you mentioned in your reply to my original comment) you do the calculation per datapoint for each given quadrant and store this information as a list for each datapoint. That way it's *calculated once* for each data point and doesn't need to be done repeatedly (since the data points never change).

Comment: Calculate what in advance, exactly? The red point changes with each search, so the black datapoints' distances to that red point and the quadrants that divide the black datapoints also change with each search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I have modified the original answer to run under `numba`. It now does a 1,000 point dataset in 3 microseconds - so considerably faster compared to the original 1 millisecond or so.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random, sys
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def QuadNearestNeighbour(dataset,redX,redY):
   # Distance to and index of nearest point in each quadrant
   dst = np.zeros(4) + 1.0e308           # Start large! Update with something smaller later
   idx = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.uint32)
   for i in nb.prange(dataset.shape[0]):
      # Get this point's x,y
      x, y = dataset[i,0], dataset[i,1]
      # Get quadrant of this point (minus 1)
      if x>redX:
         if y>redY:
             Q = 0
         else:
             Q = 1
      else:
         if y>redY:
             Q = 3
         else:
             Q = 2

      # Get distance (squared) of this point - square root is slow and unnecessary
      d = (x-redX)*(x-redX) + (y-redY)*(y-redY)
      # Update if nearest
      if d<dst[Q]:
         dst[Q] = d
         idx[Q] = i

   return  dst, idx

# Number of points
Npts = 1000

# Generate the Npts random X,Y points
dataset = np.random.rand(Npts,2)

# Generate random red pixel (X,Y)
redX, redY = random.random(), random.random()

res = QuadNearestNeighbour(dataset,redX,redY)
print(res)
```

---

**Original Answer**

This runs under 1ms for 1,000 points - timed over 1,000 different locations for the red point.

This will generate a single dataset with 1,000 points in it and then generate 1,000 red centres and do the 4 quadrants for each of the centres. It runs in under a second on my MacBook, so 1ms per red centre.

I am sure it could be optimised further by taking out extraneous `print` statements, not working out things just used for illustration, maybe using `numba` but it's enough for one day.

I haven't added lots of error checking or edge cases, it is not production quality code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

# Let's get some repeatable randomness
np.random.seed(42)

# Number of points, number of iterations
Npts, Niter = 1000, 1000

# Generate the Npts random X,Y points
dataset = np.random.rand(Npts,2)

# Run lots of iterations for better timing
for n in range(Niter):

   # Generate random red pixel (X,Y)
   red = np.random.rand(1,2)

   # Work out a Boolean mask for the 4 quadrants
   above = dataset[:,0]>red[0,0]
   right = dataset[:,1]>red[0,1]
   Q1 = np.logical_and(above,right)       # top-right
   Q2 = np.logical_and(above,~right)      # top-left
   Q3 = np.logical_and(~above,~right)     # bottom-left
   Q4 = np.logical_and(~above,right)      # bottom-right

   Q = 1
   for quadrant in [Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4]:
       print(f'Quadrant {Q}: ')
       # Boolean mask to select points in this quadrant
       thisQuad = dataset[quadrant]
       l = len(thisQuad)
       if l==0:
           print('No points in quadrant')
           continue
       # print(f'nPoints in quadrant: {l}')
       # print(f'Points: {dataset[quadrant]}')
       # Calculate distance of each point in dataset to red point
       distances = cdist(thisQuad, red, 'sqeuclidean')
       # Choose nearest
       idx = np.argmin(distances)
       print(f'Index: {idx}, point: {thisQuad[idx]}, distance: {distances[idx]}')
       Q += 1
```

Comment: I was expecting some sort of clever tree structure they'd use for video games, but hey, if brute force works, it works. I'll test it out when I can get to my laptop.

Comment: It appears that your numba version did 1 red point while your original version did 1000. I made some edits to make the comparison closer and posted timings. I'm very impressed by Numba's performance with unvectorized code; I should look into that.